# How to have a Jenkins build step that downloads a URL?

Tags: url, jenkins

I'd like to have a Jenkins build step which just downloads a given URL into the workspace.  Is there a simple way to do that?

(I currently use an Ant script which does a simple [`<get/>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html).  But that means I need to have that script in SVN somewhere, and check it out during the build.  I find that cumbersome.)

*Update:* To clarify, I'd like to download a URL without installing additional software on the build system or using an additional script. (A Jenkins plugin is fine, of course.) Preferably I don't want to depend on the build slave being Linux, Windows, or whatever.

Comment: There is also the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin), but it does not appear to be able to save the response.

Comment: @MartinBa so how is the above plugin helpful?

Comment: @Dejel - at the moment not at all I think, but it would be feasible to add it (after all they added optional logging of the response).

Comment: @MartinBa What do you suggest to use? I downloaded URL SCM plugin but I couldn't see how to use it - didn't find it in build step

Comment: @Dejel - feel free to open a new question here on SO, then we don't need to mess up the comment section on this one.

Comment: @MartinBa I opened one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744662/jenkins-plugin-to-download-remotely-file-over-https I will appreciate if you can have a look at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the [URL SCM](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+SCM) plugin? It seems like it has the functionality you are looking for. There are also other URL-based [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) available for Jenkins that you can explore.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that URL SCM plugin, but since Jenkins only supports one SCM plugin for a job, using the URL SCM plugin would conflict with our need for Subversion checkouts... :-(  And the only other plugin I found was the [URL Change Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+Change+Trigger) plugin; are there others?

Comment: The only other one I can see is the [URLTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin) plugin.

Comment: Both URL Change Trigger and URLTrigger don't put anything in the workspace, so they don't help me here...

Comment: Try using the [Multiple SCMs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) plugin to configure two SCMs in one job. Otherwise, my only other suggestion would be to configure dependencies between jobs. Use the URL SCM plugin in one of those jobs and make it the downstream job of the one that uses Subversion.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, that would work. But the first line of the docs makes me worry: "This plugin is more of a proof-of-concept than a robust and fully functional component."  I guess I'm staying with Ant for now.  And perhaps I'll just create an 'URL dowload build step' plugin myself. :-)

Comment: I'll mark this one as the answer, since I may switch to this in the future.  It's not what I was hoping for, but it would work.

Comment: If you can create a plugin to meet this need, I'm sure that others will appreciate your efforts.

Comment: How do I use this plugin? I installed it but don't find any build step to support it

Answer (score 11):

How Download file with Jenkins HTTP Request Plugin. 
How to download file into Jenkins workspace.
I was downloading a tar.gz file from our Nexus (Artifactory) which is a local repository into work-space of a Jenkins build steps. 
Steps to be done:

1. Add build step "Http Request", obviously you need to have https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin .
2. Specify your URL and HTTP method.
3. Open  "Advanced.." configuration. (Click it)
4. Go to Response section.
5. Use "Output Response to file" field to specify name and extension of your file
6. [Please use this screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieYIb.png)
7. after download you can find desired file inside your workspace with name that you specified in step# 5.

Comment: @Alistair: You can use the GUI to generate pipeline code. From a pipeline job that has embedded pipeline script, select Pipeline Syntax link below the script box. Hope that's enough to get you going.

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't want to meddle with installing plugins or running shell commands (e.g. there might be no `curl` on windows), you may do this programmatically:

```java
file_text = new URL ("https://some.site.com/some_file.html").getText()
writeFile(file: 'file.html', text: file_text)
```

To run this you will need to make some [in-process script approvals](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) as usual with custom code in Jenkins.

In cause you need to configure actual request, check [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html#getText()) for `getText()` parameters.

Based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kdabir/1885071) and [this answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809461/jenkins-java-io-filenotfoundexception-permission-denied-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-g)

Comment: Do you know how to add headers for authentication? The documentation you linked doesn't say anything about headers.

Comment: @ErikB just googled this http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2014/02/setting-headers-url-requests-with-groovy/ Will this do?

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is just to have a shell script build step that does a wget or curl on your URL.  But the plugins that @Bernard suggests will probably give you additional functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, I do something similar already (but using Ant instead of a shell script, which gives me cross-platform behavior).  As I said, my problem is that this gives me an extra SVN checkout.  Alternatively, I could install an additional script or build file on our Jenkins slaves, but that makes maintenance more difficult.

Comment: Seems a good, solid way. Arguable whether it is simplest or even simpler than other suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin works great to do a get/put/post/delete on any REST type url: HTTP Request Plugin - on the Jenkins Wiki ; https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin

Comment: That does not answer the question-- I do not want to just do an HTTP request, I want to use the _result_ of a GET request.  And as @MartinBa already mentioned in the first comment on the question, that does not seem to be possible with this plugin: it is only possible to _log_ the response.

Comment: I was testing a really trivial case, but for me, the output appeared in the Jenkins console log, so I would have been able to parse/use it. I can see that might be annoying, but would it not solve the problem? Also, this plugin differs from the one shown above.