# Jenkins plugin to download remotely file over https

Tags: jenkins, vmware

I need to download file from https (authentication required) to a remote VMware Server Virtual Machine

Is there a plugin in Jenkins to do it?

I need to download from the location the last updated file that has the name "suite"

I downloaded [SCM URL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+SCM), but didn't find a build step to run it. Also, I am not sure if it's the right plugin for it

Comment: Are you running a Jenkins slave on the VMWare VM? If so you could use curl and have a job just to run on that node

Comment: Hi I am running it from another windows machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [URL SCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+SCM) *does not provide a build step* because it gives you the ability to have a certain URL as SCM (one SCM *per job*).

So you need an extra job with the URL as Source code provider.

---

It strikes me that [`Wget`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) may be what you're looking for. Just have a [*Execute Shell* / *Batch Command*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-ShellScriptsandWindowsBatchCommands) step that invokes Wget for your URL and saves it to the current `%WORKSPACE%`.

(Actually that's what [gareth-bowles suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7123735/321013) over at the other question.) Do note that there is also a [wget for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: So that's not what I am looking for. What do you suggest to use? it's part of the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a job with two steps:

1. Download the file to Jenkins using the [SCM URL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/URL+SCM) plugin.
2. Publish to remote vm using [Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) plugin

Comment: Thanks. How do I use the SCM URL? it doesn't say on their page and I don't see a step with it

Comment: Also, I need to download the latest updated file on a location with a name like "suite". is it possible to do that?

Comment: If you have installed the SCM URL plugin, it brings a new option in the SCM part of job configuration page. Instead of Git or SVN you can choose URL and provide a URL to be polled. As the plugin documentation says, it will poll the URL and download the file the URL points to and saves it to the job workspace.

Comment: How do I specify credentials?